# Methods of mix thick liquids (3D printer Resin), stir, shake or acoustic?

Tags: mixtures

Most of the 3D printing community mixes resins by hand by simply shaking them.
This is not 100% effective (I believe) and also creates a lot of bubbles that get in the prints.
What method would you recommend?

I have tried stirring or rather rolling the 1-liter bottle for 10 minutes to let it stir.
Also, I read a little about Ultrasonic Homogenizers but I only have an ultrasonic cleaning machine. Is that strong enough to excite the two main compounds in the resin or should I use something stronger?

Thank you!

Comment: What is common practice when handling epoxy resin or PDMS is to stir it with a spatula or the like for several minutes and then to degas it with a void pump (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SHXuC1lIGj4). This kind of things sells as kits for one or two hundred €/$ and are just the perfect way for it. Shaking might require less time but surely produces more bubbles than stirring. By stirring gently but thoroughly, you can actually reach perfect mixing without introducing to much bubbles... I do not know acoustical stirring but it mights generate bubble as well through cavitation...

Comment: You might put in some glass marbles to improve agitation and roll on a rock-tumbler or similar device. Fill to the very top to avoid introducing bubbles. Rock tumblers are available for as low as US$30, or make one from LEGOs. For a thicker the liquid, use slower rotation.

Comment: Little viscous liquids are better to be shaken, viscous liquids are better to be stirred. Shaking of e.g. honey with a thick starch sol would not be particularly helpful.